# Creating plot from CSV with matplotlib fails

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot from csv using pandas but the image that I get it is blank any help.

```
def graph(request):

    fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    data_df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\csvdata.csv")
    data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_df)
    data_df.plot(ax=ax)
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
    plt.close(fig)
    response = HttpResponse(buf.getvalue(), content_type = 'image/png')

    return response
```

Comment: If you just plot the graph in Python do you get anything? What happens if you print the data frame? Does it have any data? Are you sure it's able to read that file?

Comment: First I get image but white image no thing in it . second I don't know if it's read csv file correctly or not but I'm sure it's read csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course we cannot know the content of the csv file and hence cannot know if it's read in correctly. But suppose it is, the problem would be that you are using pyplot to save a figure which has not been registered with pyplot.

You can either use pyplot as

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
data_df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\csvdata.csv")
data_df.plot(ax=ax)
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
plt.close(fig)
```

or create the figure without pyplot, but then also not use pyplot to save it

```
fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
data_df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\csvdata.csv")
data_df.plot(ax=ax)
buf = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buf, format='png')
```